# how to equal 2 date variable in c#

Tags: c#

```
DateTime dt=Convert.ToDateTime(data);
    if ((dt.Year == DateTime.Now.Year) 
       && (dt.Month == DateTime.Now.Month) 
       && (dt.Day == DateTime.Now.Day))
    lblDate.Text = "Today";
```

This code too lazy

1. How to compare 2 date variables the easy way?
2. How to get the difference of 2 date variables in minutes?

Comment: someone please correct grammar in the question. Also 'equal' should be replaced with 'compare'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the first question:

- In general:

  ```
  if (first.Date == second.Date)
  ```
- To check whether a `DateTime` is "today"

  ```
  if (dateTime.Date == DateTime.Today)
  ```

Note that this doesn't take any time zone issues into consideration... What do you want to happen if the other `DateTime` is in UTC, for example?

I'm not sure what you mean by the second question. Could you elaborate? You can do:

```
TimeSpan difference = first - second;
```

if that's any help... look at the [`TimeSpan` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) for more information about what's available. For instance, you may mean:

```
double minutes = (first - second).TotalMinutes;
```

but you may not...

Answer (score 6):

```
1. DateTime.Equals(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt=Convert.ToDateTime(data);
if (dt.Date == DateTime.Today)
    lblDate.Text = "Today";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use subtract Method

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt=Convert.ToDateTime(data);
id(dt==DateTime.Now)
{
    lblDate.Text = "Today";
}
```

Comment: I think you miss the part where the Time part is stripped away.

Comment: I thinks you're Right. I'm Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. if (dt.Date == DateTime.Today)

2. (first - second).TotalMinutes
```